# Function pointed by derived class pointer

Tags: c++, inheritance

I was recently asked this in an interview. Given the code:

```
class A{
    public:
       void f() { cout << "f in A" << endl; }
};

class B : public A{
    public:
       void g() { cout << "g in B" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    B *p2 = new B;    
}
```

Which function does pointer p2 point to ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure it points to no function? Just the object B itself? Could be wrong.

Comment: That's not a function pointer.

Comment: @Pubby In memory, what will p2 point to then ? Also, what could be the intent of asking this question ?

Comment: Agreed. Sounds like you either remembered wrong, or it was a trick question.

Comment: @Aaron The question is right.

Comment: @Jake It will point to the memory allocated by `new B`.

Comment: Is the point that there is no storage in `A` or `B`?  It doesn't seem to have anything to do with function pointers.

Comment: Perhaps they were testing your willingness to take a risk and point out the obvious flaw in the question then.  Who knows what interviewers think. :)  Hope you get the job.

Comment: a pointer to B can only point to an object of type B. full stop. Its value may coincide with the address of anything, but this is not what it points to, even if there is no object of type `B` at that address.

Answer (score 2):

`p2` is not a function pointer. `p2` is just pointing to the memory allocated by `new B`, not a function.

Answer (score 1):

Hmpf. p2 points to an instance of class B. So it could also point

-implementation specific and by accident- point to function g (if you apply some strange casts),

but this is rather pointless.
p2 just points to an instance of class B, and if you like, you can invoke that instances method g. And if you are even more adventurous, you can even invoke method f of B's base class A's method f. Anything else is just implementation dependant and makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

`p2` does not point to a function but to an instance of `class B`. Not only is it not a function pointer (as the other answers have pointed out), but the address it points to is not also the address of any function in almost any implementation. If `class B` had non-static data members, `p2` would also coincide with the address of the first non-static data member (but it would not point to that as its not a pointer to that type of object!). However, this does not work for member methods: member function pointers don't depend on the object.

Very strange to have such a nonsense question in an interview. Perhaps the interviewers wanted to show their ignorance of basic programming.